# Set the value of a new byte using a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string with a numerical value that will fit into a data type byte variable (e.g. "243").

I want to set the byte to the numerical value of the string, something similar to `byte myByte = 243;` but using the string instead. How would this be possible?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0s9b1y3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use this to convert your string value to byte:

```
byte MyByte = Convert.ToByte("243");
```

Comment: A little bit of explaination might not go amiss. You probably see that other answers recommend other methods, so its probably worth elaborating why you recommend your method of doing it, what that actually does, and caveats / further problems the OP has to avoid using your method.

Comment: Please don't use ASCII smileys in answer, they're not required. I've removed that for you now, please don't include those in any post.

Answer (score 4):

Use `byte.Parse()` method:

```
byte myByte = byte.Parse("243");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
string myString = "243";
var byteData = Convert.ToByte(myString);
```